# Look for term/name about non-trivial programming language extentions

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

Such things like:

- `alloc/free`, `pthread_*`, `longjump` in С
- `Thread`, `ThreadLocal`, `ClassLoader`, `JavaCompiler`, `java.lang.instrument`, `WeakReference` etc in Java
- C++ template language extension (back in the past)
- runtime binary/byte code instrumentation

require especial support from runtime and add new semantic to language which can't be expressed by language itself.

Also assembler language extension or external modules or build-in reflection API have access to runtime and can change behavior.

I look for term that give name for such language extension in general which bring new semantic to language that can't be expressed by usual language constructs.

Comment: The term would be "language extension".

Comment: malloc/free can be (and I have) implemented in ordinary C.

Comment: @MSalters Do you implement it by using knowledge about platform depended memory addresses or syscalls?

Comment: Yes. But knowledge about the _system_, expressed in ordinary language constructs do not make a new language extension. It's no different than writing `const float g=9.81`. That encodes information about gravity in an ordinary language construct, it's in no way a language extension.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about a **Directitive** or a **Pragma**. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_%28programming%29):

> In computer programming, a directive or pragma (from "pragmatic") is a
>   language construct that specifies how a compiler (or assembler or
>   interpreter) should process its input. Directives are not part of the
>   language proper – they are not part of the grammar, and may vary from
>   compiler to compiler – but instead function either as an in-band form
>   of a command-line option, specifying compiler behavior, or are
>   processed by a preprocessor. In some cases directives specify global
>   behavior, while in other cases they only affect a local section, such
>   as a block of programming code. In some cases, such as some C pragmas,
>   directives are optional compiler hints, and may be ignored, but
>   normally they are prescriptive, and must be followed. However, a
>   directive does not perform any action in the language itself, but
>   rather only a change in the behavior of the compiler.